# How frequent does Tomcat rotate JSESSIONID within same session

Tags: java, tomcat7, sessionid

I was trying to scan a Webapp hosted in Tomcat and faced some difficulty and later realized even within the same session for an user tomcat changes JSESSIONID (monitored using Fiddler). I could not find any configuration in server.xml as such. Any info on this would be helpful

I would assume Tomcat would do this to defend Session Fixation

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe default session timeout for Servlet, is 30 minutes.

Can be altered with `<session-timeout>` in web.xml.